# node.js seems to go into sleep mode when it's not in use

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, http

My node.js http server has a response time of 2-3ms on localhost. But when I don't use it for a minute the "first" requests take around 300-400ms. After that node.js is fast again.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end("Hello");
});
server.listen(90);
```

Is there some kind of sleep mode for V8 or does it drop the JIT information when they're not in use for a while?

Comment: This sounds more like a configuration issue with your server.  What kind of server are you running?

Comment: I'm just using the build-in http Server from node.js. My testmachine is a Windows 7 x64 (tested on two machines).

Comment: I would guess that there are some power management settings on your Windows machine that are causing this.  For servers to be highly responsive, they must be tuned differently than typical desktop power management.  I don't have this issue when running node.js on my Raspberry Pi hardware - though I did turn off most power management settings on the Pi that make the Pi go to sleep (these are OS settings, not node.js settings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `jfriend00` said in his comment: [node.js seems to go into sleep mode when it's not in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782037/node-js-seems-to-go-into-sleep-mode-when-its-not-in-use#comment40323942_25782037) it seems to be a Windows issue, not a node.js one.